# How to run perl code block under debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I'm writing a test for my debugger.

```
subtest "main" => sub {
    $ENV{PERL5DB} = 'Devel::AllSubs';
    my $stderr = capture_stderr {
        sub foo { bar(); }
        sub bar { 1; }
        foo();
    };
    $ENV{PERL5DB} = '';
    is $stderr, "main::foo\nmain::bar";
};
```

How to apply debugger to

```
{
sub foo { bar(); }
sub bar { 1; }
foo();
}
```

block ?

I tried to use `$ENV{PERL5DB}` but no effect.

Comment: Why do you declare subroutines within `capture_stderr` ? This is unlikely to do what you want.

Comment: Usually, you can set a breakpoint from within your program by setting ` $DB::single = 1` at the location where you want to interrupt.

Comment: @Corion, Devel::AllSubs is a module they wrote and that they are trying to test.

Comment: the debugger won't work on code that's compiled normally.  to turn on debugging, you'd have to use Enbugger.  but I don't know that PERL5DB is checked at runtime even then

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `$ENV{PERL5DB}` the way you want.

1. It has to be the full command to load in the debugger code such as `use Devel::AllSubs`
2. It is only checked when Perl is started with a bare `-d` switch
3. It only gets checked when Perl starts as Perl needs to know that it is running the script under the debugger to create the op codes needed to enter the debugger.

So in order to apply your debugger to only part of the code you will need to first load it in using the -d switch like this

```
perl -d:AllSubs script.pl
```

and then use a package variable to decide if you want to process the code or not. Looking at your module name I assume you are trying to do something with each subroutine so your test probably wants to be in your `DB::sub` method

Comment: So there is no way to run just part of code under `-d` flag ?

Comment: @PaulSerikov I don't think so no, however the Perl debugger `perl5db.pl` has a lot of documentation in it and might be useful. Note that under normal circumstances I would not recommend delving into the guts of the debugger but as you are writing your own debugger it might be worth it.

Comment: You might also want to look at tests for other debuggers, like https://metacpan.org/source/AWWAIID/Devel-ebug-0.59/t